# Scenario when both pagination and the number of records to be shown in a page are combined

Tags: user-expectation, pagination, ux-designer

With both pagination and number of records to be shown in a page are implemented, if the user is in some 3rd page and changes the number of records to something higher,  there could be situation where the number of pages is reduced to 2. Should the user be taken to the 2nd page in this case? 
If yes, what if the number of pages is increased? In this case it is better the user is not taken to the last page. 
 Or in a better way, Could the user be taken to the first page in both the scenarios? 
It would also be great if anyone could suggest a few better websites where pagination is implemented along with the number of records to be shown in a page.

Comment: Quite confusing, do you have any image? or can you please make more clear?

Answer (score 1):

This happens quite regularly on sites like Amazon and eBay where they simply revert to the first page of the results.

Ideally, you would maintain the items currently in view and recalculate the pages and their content around that but this is technically very difficult and impossible when the number of items per page is *reduced*. (How can we know which items the user is viewing)

So, although not perfect, the solution of reverting back to the first page of results seems to be the best currently available choice.

Comment: Doing the math to identify a few set of rows and moving to the page where those set of records are located is not much difficult but in the experience way, it matters a lot as there are high chances for the user to be found no where all at a sudden. Moving to the first page is a better option by allowing the user to type the page number that he wants to be in or by allowing him to search across the results

Comment: I don't agree with the part starting "Ideally".  I think recalculating the pages would be confusing to the user, who would not end up knowing where they were.  I would probably manually go to page 1 if this happened to me.